# Derivative of the product of stochastic variable and a function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I have an equation

$$S_{t} = B_{t}M_{t}-N_{t}$$

where $M_{t}$, $N_{t}$ are Geometric Brownian motions given by

$$dM_{t}=uM_{t}dt+\beta M_{t}dW_{t}$$
$$dN_{t}=nN_{t}dt+\alpha N_{t}dW_{t}$$
where $\mu$, $\beta$, $n$, and $\alpha$ are constants.

and $B_{t}$ is a function

$$B_{t} =\int_{t}^{T}\frac{1}{M_{s}}e^{rs}ds$$,

I would like to compute $dS_{t}$, If I compute it in the following way would it be correct?

$$dS_{t}=\frac{\partial B_{t}}{\partial t}M_{t}dt+B_{t}dM_{t}-dN_{t}$$

Comment: just to be sure, are neither $B_t$ nor $\beta_t$ brownian motions? what is the regularity of the drifts/volatility in the SDE defining $M$ and $N$? What are $X$ and $u_t$?

Comment: I have modified my question, there was a typo, $X_{t}$ should have been $N_{t}$. The drifts and volatility terms are constants, i.e. $\mu$, $\beta$, $n$, and $\alpha$ are constants.

Comment: ***Hint:*** Your last formula looks correct but is not everything. From $S_t=B_tM_t-N_t$ we get using the well-known [integration-by-parts formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation#Semimartingales):
$$dS_t=M_t\,dB_t+B_t\,dM_t+d\langle B,M\rangle_t-dN_t\,.$$ The only two things you have to see now how $dB_t$ and the covariation of $B$ and $M$ look like.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks, If $B_{t}=\int_{t}^{T} e^{rs}ds$, then $B_{t}$ does not depend on any stochastic process and is not correlated with $M_{t}$, in that case would my $dS_{t}$ calculation in the above question is correct?

Comment: Much simpler. Even with that $M$ in it $B_t$ is differentiable in $t\,.$ Therefore, $\langle B,M\rangle\equiv 0$ and $dB_t=(-e^{rt}/M_t)\,dt$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus. Now write out my equation for $dS_t$ and cancel the $M$ in the first term.